# "nvm use 11.0.0" command not working, I tried setting environment variables , but it ain't working

Tags: nvm

I am getting this while installing nvm. I have tried using setting environment variables.

[image: Environment variables]
[image: nvm command not working]

Comment: Welcome, Piyush! Could you please copy the error you are getting in as text instead of just including it as an image? It is much easier for users on mobile devices to read it that way, and it can be selected/copied/pasted, etc.

Comment: Following is the error I am getting, exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Piyush' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.